# How can I detect spaces in a textbox for later adding up all the numbers that the user has entered in the texbox C# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, split

I want to make a small program, that people put their wedding expenses separated by spaces and return them the total. This in C# winforms.

The code:

```
string expenses = txEntrada.Text;
int add = 0;
string space = "";
for (int i = 0; i < expenses.Length; i++)
{
    string substring = expenses.Substring(i, 1);
    if (substring == space)
    {
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        add += int.Parse(substring);
    }
}
txSortida.Text = add.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
txSortida.Text =
    txEntrada
        .Text
        .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
        .Sum()
        .ToString();
```

Comment: Side note: `x.Trim()` is redundant here: the first reason is that you have splitted by `' '` and the second is that `int.Parse` is smart enough to parse strings with leading and trailing spaces like `"   123  "`. I'd rather add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to tolerate leading and trailing spaces for the input like `"  123    456  "`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Good call on both counts.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like this:

```
txSortida.Text = txEntrada
  .Text
  .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Sum(item => decimal.TryParse(item, out var cost) ? cost : 0.00m)
  .ToString("c2");
```

Here we

1. Split the input by spaces `' '` and remove empty entry in order to tolerate *leading*, *trailing* and *double* spaces like `" 123    456 "` input.
2. We sum parsed values (since we work with cash, `decimal` is often the best choice; if you insist on `int` put `int.TryParse` instead); if value is of wrong format we *ignore it* (add `0m`), i.e. `"123 bla-bla-bla" 456 => 123 + 456 == 579`
3. Finally, we format the result in some currency format (I've chosen `c2`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use class [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0) from namespace [`System.Text.RegularExpressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions?view=net-7.0) to split the input string into tokens (each token will be one of the items in the exprenses as a string).
Then convert each token into an `int` and sum them up.

Code example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
//...

// Split into tokens:
string[] tokens = Regex.Split(expenses, " +");   // use + to inidcate one or more spaces between tokens.

// Sum up the values:
int sum = 0;
foreach (string token in tokens)
{
    if (int.TryParse(token, out int val)) 
    { 
        sum += val; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        // Handle error ...
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Output:

```
321
```

In your actual code after calculating `sum` you can use:

```
txSortida.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, but without arrays would there be any way to do it? Because I know how to traverse strings more or less, but not how to traverse numbers.

Comment: What is the issue you have with traversing an array ? also the array here is one of strings not numeric values (each token is a string), although the strings do contain numeric values (which is why `int.Parse` is used).

Answer (score 0):

you can using `expenses.Split` To convert String to array based on space, and   property `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` remove Empty in array. then use `Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))`  to sum the array as a number

```
 int add = 0;
 string expenses = txEntrada.Text;
 txSortida.Text =  expenses.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

Comment: `expenses` is a string, and therefore `expenses[i]` is a single character. I don't see how parsing single characters solves the OP's issue.

Comment: @wohlstad Instead of `substring(i,1)`, `expenses[i].ToString()` is used.

Comment: Also calling `Replace` will eliminate the spaces between the integer values.  Have you tried your code with e.g. `expenses = "1 100";` ?

Comment: @wohlstad Yes, I tested the code. For your example, the result is 2 and there is no problem

Comment: I understood that the OP would like to get `101` in this case (_"people put their wedding expenses separated by spaces and return them the total"_). I think each expense can be more than 1 digit.

Comment: @wohlstad Thank you for your attention. I thought the characters should be summed and edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this robust and not crash if user puts in extra spaces or non-numeric characters, I would recommend using the [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) method for `int`. So first you would split the string with the `Split` method, using the option to `RemoveEmptyEntries`. Then go through that array with the `TryParse` method, adding in the value only if the parsing succeeds.

[image: screenshot]

```
private void calculateSum()
{
    int sum = 0;
    string[] values = txEntrada.Text.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    List<string> goodValues = new List<string>();
    foreach (var entry in values)
    {
        if(int.TryParse(entry, out int value))
        {
            sum += value; 
            goodValues.Add(entry);
        }
    }
    txSortida.Text = sum.ToString();
    txEntrada.Text = string.Join(" ", goodValues);
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txEntrada.SelectAll()));
}
```